# KnockoutJs template and event Binding

Tags: knockout.js

With reference to the fiddle below:
[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/gokuldahal/xrnecuve/1/)

```
<div id="test">
    <li>gokul</li>
</div>

<script id="someTemplate" type="text/html">
        <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</script>


var data = [ { name: "one" }, { name: "two" } ];

var element = document.getElementById("test");
var startForEach = document.createComment("ko template: {name: 'someTemplate', foreach: $data }");
var endForEach = document.createComment("/ko");

element.appendChild(startForEach);
element.appendChild(endForEach);

ko.applyBindings(data, document.getElementById("test"));
```

Now to the list item, i need to add a class based on some javascript logic. Eg we have elementArray1=[100, 200, 300], elementArray2=[500, 800, 800] ElementSearch= some Random Number If this random number is in either of this two elementArray, we need to add class "activated" to the list item.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="20" data-pid="400">
<div id="test">
    <li>gokul</li>
    </div></div>

<script id="someTemplate" type="text/html">
        <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</script>


var data = [ { name: "one" }, { name: "two" } ];
data.myPostProcessingLogic = function (element) {
    val=$(element).parent().parent().attr('data-pid');
    if(val==400){
    $(element).addClass('hello');
        console.log($(element));
    }
};
var element = document.getElementById("test");
var startForEach = document.createComment("ko template: {name: 'someTemplate', foreach: $data, afterRender: myPostProcessingLogic }");
var endForEach = document.createComment("/ko");

element.appendChild(startForEach);
element.appendChild(endForEach);

ko.applyBindings(data, document.getElementById("test"));
```